# Why wasn't I awarded an "Enlightened" badge for this answer?

Tags: support, badges

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23635362/3549027

It seems to meet all the criteria:

- First to answer
- Score of 10 or more
- Accepted by asker

Does the answer need to have a score of >= 10 *before* it is accepted? If so, that seems counter-productive since it would penalize answers that were so good they were accepted immediately.

I *did* receive a "Nice answer" badge the moment it got the tenth vote, and I can see that other people have received "Enlightened" within the last hour, so it's not simply that badges are being delayed or that some script needs to run.

Examination of other answers that were just awarded "Enlightened" this morning shows that they were posted and accepted months ago--in at least one case more than a year ago. This leads me to believe that either these answers just got their 10th votes today (but then why doesn't mine count?), or that there is a looooooooong delay here. Or perhaps that there is a delay after receiving the tenth vote?

Comment: Patience, young grasshopper.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The script that awards the Enlightened badge doesn't run as often as the one that awards the Nice Answer badge.

It will take a little while for the badge to be awarded.

In the unlikely event that it still hasn't been awarded 24 hours after hitting the +10 score *then* contact the team.