# Enlightened badge awarded with a bit of delay?

Tags: support, badges

I've received an [`Enlightened badge`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/19/enlightened?userid=1140748) today, I thought it was weird because I didn't get any upvote on this answer for a while.

Actually I've looked in my reputation history until September 2014 and I've not found any upvote for this.

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254832/1140748) the badge should have been awarded 24 hours after the 10th upvote.

So the delay here seems to be a bit longer :)

Any idea on what did happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another user answered the question before you.  Enlightened's requirements are:

> **First to answer** and accepted with score of 10 or more. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

(emphasis mine).

The other answer was deleted 4 hours ago, making your answer now eligible.

Comment: Thanks! Actually I can't see deleted answers yet. I didn't remeber there was another answer before.

Comment: My gut feeling says 'first to answer' should include deleted answers...

Comment: @Joe You can propose that change if you want.  Clearly the existing implementation is different.